# Get screen size in EJS

Tags: ejs

I'm working in an EJS template and I need to determine the screen size. I'm using Grunt & Browserfy to compile (apologies if this is the wrong terminology). Using window.screen.width or window.matchMedia returns an error that window is not defined. What would be the best way to access this information?

Answering my own question: I understand now that EJS is rendered on the server so there is no screen to reference. I ended up using Javascript to accomplish what I needed since it's rendered in the browser. It's messier than I wanted but works nonetheless.

Comment: I think ejs only for render dom, show if you determine the screen size, you should use javascript like jquery, and only get when document is loaded

Comment: Hi! Can you share some code?

Answer (score 0):

Try just using `screen.width` without the "window" in front.